# Python3 socket client inside thread

Tags: multithreading, sockets, python-3.x

I required to grep a status from multiple RPi every minute using python3, the status is grep by connecting to the socket and run a json command.

Every 15 minute the status will be save to mysql database, else it will be put in the memcached

currently I have more than 10 RPi, is there a way to optimize it ?
We planning to grow to 100 Rpi.

Here is my simplify thread

```
class getStatus(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, rpi, status_queue):
        super().__init__()
        self.rpi = rpi
        self.status_queue = status_queue

    def run(self):
        r = b""

        try:
            s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            s.settimeout(1)
            s.connect((self.rpi.get("ip_address"), 9999))

            cmd = json.dumps({"command":"status"})
            s.send(cmd.encode())

            while True:
                recv = s.recv(1024)
                if not recv:
                    break
                else:
                    r += recv

            s.close()
        except:
            s.close()

        if len(r) > 0:
            r = r[:r.index(b"\x00")]

        self.status_queue.put({"rpi": self.rpi, "status": r})
```

This how I run the thread

```
if name == "__main__":
    import_time = int(time.time())
    exact_second = import_time % 60
    import_time = import_time - exact_second

    minute = int(time.strftime("%M", time.gmtime(import_time))) 

    #Retrieve rpi list from mysql, each rpi has element id and ip_address
    rpis = get_rpi_list() 

    threads = []
    status_queue = queue.Queue()

    for rpi in rpis:
        threads.append(getStatus(rpi, status_queue))

    for t in threads:
        t.daemon = True
        t.start()

    for t in threads:
        while t.is_alive():
            t.join()

    status_queue.put(None)
    #Iter the queue so we can save it on db one by one
    for q in iter(status_queue.get, None):
        if not q.get('status') is None:
            #If not 15 minute then I save it to memcached
            save_to_mc(q.get('rpi').get('id'), q.get('status'))
            #If 15 minute I save it to mysql
            if (minute % 15) == 0:
                save_to_db(q.get('rpi').get('id'), q.get('status'), int(import_time))
```

Comment: Check out `netcat`, `cron`, `batch`, you are reinventing the wheel. ;)

Comment: I run this script using cron, so If I set cron for each rpi it will be too much cause I have another cron job.